# Does this Latin make sense?

Tags: classical-latin, translation-check, motto

I want to use a motto "always seize the future" as a company slogan. Does "capere semper in posterum" make sense? I got it from Google Translate and based on Spanish-English translations from that site, I trust it for single words but not always for phrases.

Comment: Welcome to the site! The question is good, but it would benefit from some details. How did you come up with that translation? What makes you suspicious about it? // Translating a motto is notoriously difficult. Explaining the intention behind it can help greatly. // We have a [guide for asking translation questions](http://meta.latin.stackexchange.com/q/143/79).

Comment: Hi! I'm using it as a company slogan. I got it from Google Translate and based on Spanish-English translations from that site, I trust it for single words but not always for phrases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Google Translate is [notoriously bad](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79) with Latin.
It seems to have little understanding of Latin grammar.
If you only want single words, you are much better off using an [online Latin dictionary of your choice](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79).
I do not know an online service (or any computerized tool) that translates Latin reliably.

The Latin phrase *capere semper in posterum* means roughly "to always take from this point on".
It makes little sense.
(This is the default answer to "does this result from Google translate make sense?" in my experience.)

Instead, I suggest ***semper futura carpito***.

A good translation for "to seize" in your context is *carpere*.
I chose the future imperative *carpito* instead of the present *carpe* (which would also be fine) to give it a more festive feel.
If you want it to be more mundane, use *carpe*, but its pronunciation is more ambiguous to an Anglophone.
I am not sure if everyone agrees with my sense of nuance here.
These imperatives are singular; if you want plural, use *carpitote* or *carpite* instead.

The verb *carpere* has several meanings, and you can study the details in [the L&S dictionary entry](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=carpo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).
It seems to mostly mean "to harvest, pick, or pluck".
I find that a reasonable (albeit somewhat poetic) translation of "seize", but if you want to explore other options, [*capere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DC%3Aentry+group%3D14%3Aentry%3Dcapio1) is a good word for "catch, seize, take in hand".
The corresponding forms are easy: just drop the R from *carpere*.
(This does not apply to all forms, but it does apply to the imperatives used here.)

There is no good Latin noun for "future".
Instead, I chose the participle *futurus* which can be seen as the adjective "future" — and the etymological source of the English word.
There are two choices: the neuter singular *futurum* and the neuter plural *futura*.
The singular means roughly "the thing in future", treating future as one.
The plural means roughly "the things in future", treating future as a series of things.
The plural sounds more idiomatic to me, and I think the nuance of the singular *futurum* would be less appropriate for this use.

The word *semper* is simply a good translation for "always".

It is up to you to make the choices *futurum/futura* and *carpe/carpito/carpite/carpitote* if you are after a different nuance.
Also the word order is relatively free in Latin.
My suggestion is what I find most fitting.

Comment: Latin doesn't seem to have an Abstract noun for "the Future."  *Futurum* (the participle) is a good substitute. Caesar uses *futurum,* but Terence has *futura* (plural) "future things,"  "things about to exist," which seems neater.

Comment: I'd second *futura* specifically because of the *semper*, since it sounds like this seizing is happening multiple times.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest *semper carpe futūra*. Here, *futura* (*futūra*) is a participle conjugated in the present tense and active voice, declined in the neuter gender, plural number, and accusative case. I chose *futūra* because the idea is not simply enjoying abstract and intangible time (singular number), but rather, enjoying the things to come in the future (plural number). I was initially under the impression that you typed *capere* rather than *carpere* as a typo, but Draconis has educated me that *capere* is indeed a verb. In any case, most people are familiar with the phrase *Carpe diem* (as opposed to *Cape diem*).

Comment: *Capere* (from *capio*) is definitely a real word, and significantly closer to "seize" than *carpere* is. The latter is better translated "harvest" or "gather" (or sometimes even "destroy"); Horace's famous *carpe diem* exhorts his listener to harvest the day's opportunities while they're ripe, rather than letting them fall to the ground by waiting too long.

Comment: (Of course in this case I agree that *carpo* is a perfectly fine verb to use. Just wanted to clarify that "seize" is not its literal meaning.)

Comment: @Draconis—Interesting! Thank you for the education. I honestly thought he meant *carpere* rather than *capere* (I assumed *capere* was a typo).

Comment: This is a good and well explained suggestion. (+1) I expanded my answer before reading yours, and tried to explain the differences between *carpe* and *carpito* and between *futura* and *futurum*.

Comment: I think *carpere* is actually not a very suitable choice (also in the answer by @JoonasIlmavirta) because as Draconis says, it means "pluck, harvest, gather"; the usual translation of *carpe diem* as "seize the day" is inaccurate. "Pluck/harvest the future" doesn't make much sense to me.