# What is the Latin equivalent of “Ever Forward” as a motto?

Tags: idiom, motto

In the workplace environment, I don’t think it is productive to dwell on what happened or keep score on who did what to whom.
In English I would summarize my motto as:

> Ever Forward

Now I am looking for an appropriate Latin equivalent, i.e., a phrase that conveys:

1. The past is behind me and does not matter too much.
2. Today is a new day, and things are good. A non-defeatist point of view.
3. We can accomplish great things by focusing on the future and not dwelling on the past.

I found [similar discussion on another Latin site](http://latindiscussion.com/forum/latin/always-moving-forward-without-fear.18082/). Maybe it helps.

Comment: Perhaps *semper prorsus.*

Comment: [This old question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2296/79) might contain some useful ideas.

Comment: What about [plus ultra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_ultra), meaning _further beyond_?

Comment: Would an "actual" motto with that translation be suitable or do you prefer a "hypothetical," one translated from scratch?

Comment: @TomAu I am not sure I know the difference between your choices. I am sure someone has already uttered what I choose.

Comment: I am the only one so far to propose "semper anticus, which is the motto of the U.S. 45th Infantry Division (now combat brigade)." The rest of my work were "examples," not additional choices.

Comment: @TomAu I meant I don't know the difference between "actual" and "hypothetical"

Comment: "Semper anticus" is a motto "actually" being used by someone (the 45th U.S. infantry). The other answers were created "hypothetically" in response to your question..

Answer (score 7):

A common motto is *semper prorsum*, "always forward." You can find examples of this [all over Google](https://books.google.com/books?id=G2ghAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA249&dq=%22semper+prorsum%22#v=onepage&q=%22semper%20prorsum%22&f=false), and is used as a way of expressing the necessity of marching forward. "Always forward, never backward" is what the link is saying in Latin—double down and don't retreat. *Semper prorsus* is a less common but still valid alternative.

If it's not too cheesy, I'd also suggest just a simple *Excelsior!*. This has now entered the common parlance as a way of saying "Onward & Upward," which I think gets to the heart of what you're intending to convey.

Comment: Very nice. Stan Lee has a patent on "Excelsior!" so I think I'll have to leave it to him :-D  Will you help this non-Latin speaker with the difference between your phrases (-sum versus -sus) ?

Comment: @C. M. Weimer _rem acu tetigisti!_

Comment: @TonyEnnis Essentially nothing. In this context, they're identical. For whatever reason, *semper prorsum* is the more common phrase, so anyone coming across it as your motto will more likely recognize that form than the other.

Answer (score 4):

From a good many possibilities, I personally should prefer *Nunc progrediamur!*, or 'Now let's press on!', 'Let's get on with things!' etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(S)) of Latin phrases, including 20 or so beginning with semper. The translation they give is *semper anticus,* which is the motto of the U.S. 45th Infantry Division (now combat brigade).

Other expressions with "semper" (always) include *semper fidelis* (always faithful), *semper fortis* (always brave), motto of the U.S. Navy, and *semper liber* (always free), which may have inspired an Italian song of a similar name from La Traviata.

Comment: First, *anticus* is a rarely used adjective, meaning "being up front," but not connoting a movement forward. It also has a very frequent homonym *antiquus* (that was too spelled *anticus* sometimes) meaning "former, previously existing," like maybe "old" but not implying *how exactly* old. It might not be the best choice of a word for a concise motto (although the U.S. 45th Infantry Division would likely disagreee with me on that). Second, this is probably not the sense the OP wanted--if I understand, a meaning that would invoke *moving* forward.

Comment: @kkm: I decided to ask the OP directly, commenting under his question.

Comment: @kkm You're correct in that I am not looking for "being in a forward position" but indeed "moving forward" but in a metaphorical sense.

Comment: @TonyEnnis: I don't know a better group for "moving forward in a metaphorical sense" than a U.S. combat group.

Answer (score 2):

"Duc in altum !" coming from the Holy Scriptures (Luke, 5,4): *dixit (Jesus) ad Simonem duc in altum et laxate retia vestra in capturam* : Launch out into the deep, and let down your nets for a draught.*