# Translation to Latin: "Forward engineering"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, technology

I am looking for a new name for my engineering company. I want to translate the English phrase 'Forward engineering' into Latin language.

Answer (score 1):

As luchonacho suggests, *ars ingeniaria* is good for "engineering".
To express the direction, I would add the adjective *prorsus*, meaning "straightforward, straight, direct" and giving rise to the concept of prose.
Thus, I'd suggest ***ars ingeniaria prorsa***.

*Prorsus* is more common as an adverb, but [it is also an adjective](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dprorsus2).
The kind of use of this adjective I proposed appears to be post-classical, but I did not consider that an issue as you did not specify an era.
I cannot think of an equally appropriate adjective that, say, Cicero would have used.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like *perge ars ingeniaria*?

*Perge* is the imperative singular of *[pergo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pergo)*, which in the intransitive (without a verb, as in this case) means to "go on, proceed, hasten, press on".

*Ars ingeniaria* is the nominative Latin of engineering, [according to Wikipedia](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ars_ingeniaria).

Also see [this post](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5258/what-is-the-latin-equivalent-of-ever-forward-as-a-motto).

Comment: Hmm... I think "forward" in "forward engineering" should be parsed as an adjective, not as an imperative. Your suggestion sounds like the order "[go] forward, engineering!" rather than a name for a type of engineering. I gave an adjectival version in an answer.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Oh, then I didn't understand the focus of the phrase. I was indeed trying to think on an imperative.